# Oracle: How can a job exist and not exist at the same time?

Tags: oracle, jobs

I am trying to fix a job by deleting it and then recreating it. But I can't because it seems to not exist when I try to drop, and then exist already when I try to create

```
Begin
        dbms_scheduler.drop_job(job_name => 'add_error_rate_sig');
        
End;
[2024-01-24 13:12:33] [99999][27475]
[2024-01-24 13:12:33]   ORA-27475: unknown job "SREAPP"."ADD_ERROR_RATE_SIG"
[2024-01-24 13:12:33]   ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_ISCHED", line 278
[2024-01-24 13:12:33]   ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER", line 751
[2024-01-24 13:12:33]   ORA-06512: at line 2
[2024-01-24 13:12:33] Position: 0
SREAPP> BEGIN
            DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB(
                    job_name => 'add_error_rate_sig',
                    job_type => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
                    job_action => 'BEGIN SREAPP.add_error_rate_sig(null); END;',
                    number_of_arguments => 0,
                    start_date => TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('2024-01-24 00:00:00.000000000 AMERICA/LOS_ANGELES',
                                                  'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF TZR'),
                    repeat_interval => 'FREQ=WEEKLY;BYHOUR=01;BYMINUTE=00',
                    end_date => NULL,
                    enabled => TRUE,
                    auto_drop => FALSE,
                    comments => 'push to error rate summary'
                );
        
        END;
[2024-01-24 13:12:44] [99999][27477]
[2024-01-24 13:12:44]   ORA-27477: "SREAPP"."ADD_ERROR_RATE_SIG" already exists
[2024-01-24 13:12:44]   ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_ISCHED", line 175
[2024-01-24 13:12:44]   ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER", line 286
[2024-01-24 13:12:44]   ORA-06512: at line 2
[2024-01-24 13:12:44] Position: 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error did not state `ADD_ERROR_RATE_SIG` was a job. It could be another object.

```
SQL> create table j1(c1 number);

Table created.

SQL> exec dbms_scheduler.drop_job('J1');
BEGIN dbms_scheduler.drop_job('J1'); END;

*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-27475: unknown job "BP"."J1"
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_ISCHED", line 278
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER", line 751
ORA-06512: at line 1


SQL> exec dbms_scheduler.create_job(job_name =>'J1', job_type => 'PLSQL_BLOCK', job_action => 'null');
BEGIN dbms_scheduler.create_job(job_name =>'J1', job_type => 'PLSQL_BLOCK', job_action => 'null'); END;

*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-27477: "BP"."J1" already exists
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_ISCHED", line 175
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER", line 286
ORA-06512: at line 1


SQL>
```

Comment: That was it. I had a stored proc with the same name as the job